# adding multiple destinations to new relic workflows using terraform

Tags: terraform, newrelic

I am trying to create a newrelic workflow using terraform modules. I am fine with creating a workflow with signle destination. But, I am trying to create a workflow with more than one destination.

## slack channel ids

```
variable "channel_ids" {
   type    = set(string)
   default = ["XXXXXXXXXX","YYYYYYYYY"]
}
```

## creating notification channels using slack channel ids

```
resource "newrelic_notification_channel" "notification_channel" {
  for_each       = var.channel_ids
  name           = "test" # will modify if required
  type           = "SLACK" # will parameterize this
  destination_id = "aaaaaaaaa-bbbbb-cccc-ddddd-eeeeeeeeee" 
  product        = "IINT"
    property {
      key   = "channelId"
      value = each.value
  }
}
```

## Now I want to create something like below (two destinations)

```
resource "newrelic_workflow" "newrelic_workflow" {
  name = "my-workflow"
  muting_rules_handling = "NOTIFY_ALL_ISSUES"

  issues_filter {
    name = "Filter-name"
    type = "FILTER"

    predicate {
      attribute = "accumulations.policyName"
      operator = "EXACTLY_MATCHES"
      values = [ "policy_name" ]
    }
  }
    destination {
      channel_id = newrelic_notification_channel.notification_channel.id
    }
    
    destination {
      channel_id = newrelic_notification_channel.notification_channel.id
    }
}
```

I tried using for_each and for loop but no luck. Any idea on how to get my desired output?

Is it possible to loop through and create multiple destinations within the same resource, like attaching multiple destination to a single workflow?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve this by using a dynamic block, which produces a dynamic number of destination blocks based on the number of elements of newrelic_notification_channel.notification_channel.

```
resource "newrelic_workflow" "newrelic_workflow" {
  name = "my-workflow"
  muting_rules_handling = "NOTIFY_ALL_ISSUES"

  issues_filter {
    name = "Filter-name"
    type = "FILTER"

    predicate {
      attribute = "accumulations.policyName"
      operator = "EXACTLY_MATCHES"
      values = [ "policy_name" ]
    }
  }

  dynamic "destination" {
    for_each = newrelic_notification_channel.notification_channel
    content {
      channel_id = destination.value.id
    }
  }
}
```